# How to download file from file download popup and save it

Tags: powershell, download

I'm trying to download a file from file download pop up and save it to a location.

I am using:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
```

Can somebody share some powershell tips/code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking: how can I use powershell to download a file?

```
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/file.txt", "~\downloads\file.txt" )
```

Where "~\" is the shortcut to your C:\users\[yourusername]\